# html and php form populate dropdown list with value user already provide in form if error happens during form submission

Tags: php, html

sorry if the title is bit confusing.i have html form with dropdown and text field and what i want is if user submit the form with errors. an error message will be displayed. Any fields already completed will be left unchanged, allowing the user to simply adjust her input and re-submit the form without having to enter all of the data again,i have manage to do with text field but i having hard time with dropdown list.
here is my html code

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo 
   htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<h4>Choose Type of product</h4>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label >Select type of Product: </label>
         <select id="slct3"  class="browser-default custom 
            select"  name="Productytype" 
            onchange="populate1(this.id,'slct4')" >
            <span class="error"><?php 
               echo $ProductytypeErr;?></span>
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Import">Import </option>
            <option value="Export"></option>
         </select>
         <span class="error"><?php echo $ProductytypeErr;?> 
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Choose Document Type: </label>
         <select id="slct4" 
            class="browser-default custom-select" 
            name="Documenttype" value="<?php echo 
               htmlspecialchars($Documenttype);?>"></select>
      </div>
      <span class="error"><?php echo 
         $Documenttype;?></span>
   </div>
</div>
<h4>Exporter Detail</h4>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="ExportName" class="form-control" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($ExportName);?>">
            <span class="error" style="color:red"><?php echo $ExportNameErr;?></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</form>
```

it's long form but that is the main part

here is my php code

```
<?php
    // variable for storing user input
        $Productytype = $Documenttype = $ExportName = $ExportEmail = ""; 


    // variable for storing error messages
     $ProductytypeErr = $DocumenttypeErr = $ExportNameErr = 
        $ExportEmailErr="";

      $ProductytypeErr = $DocumenttypeErr = $ExportNameErr = 
      $ExportEmailErr="";  

            if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                if (empty($_POST["Productytype"])) {
                    $ProductytypeErr = "Missing";
                } else {
                    $Productytype = $_POST["Productytype"];
                }

                if (isset($_REQUEST['Documenttype']) && 
                    $_REQUEST['Documenttype'] == '0') {
                    $DocumenttypeErr = "Missing";
                } else {
                    $DocumenttypeErr = $_POST["DocumenttypeErr"];
                }

                if (empty($_POST["ExportName"])) {
                    $ExportNameErr = "Please Enter name of the exporter";
                } else {
                    $ExportName = $_POST["ExportName"];
                }
```

Comment: Please use your IDE or any online formatter to autoformat code snippets into a readable format.

Comment: `if (empty($_POST["ExportName"])) { $ExportNameErr = "Please Enter name of the exporter";` A placeholder should not be the field value. Use the `placeholder` attribute of `<input>` elements. `<option>` has a `selected` attribute.